# Java NoClassDefFoundError because of "wrong" slashes

Tags: java, exception

One on my team is having a problem with a project he got from our SVN. When he tries to run a file he gets the error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: misc\test (wrong name: misc/test)
```

We really don't understand why he gets this error. Seems like the slashes are the cause of it, but I don't understand how this is a problem or how to fix it.. :(

We're both using NetBeans (I'm on 6.7.1 and he 6.8) and the built-in svn feature. I created the project om my computer, a Mac, and he's using Win7. Could this have anything to do with it? Unix and Win use different slashes for paths after all.. But I don't see how to change this because he's running the files from the IDE.

So any help would be appreciated. Thanks!
Stian

Comment: How is he running the file? E.g., what's the equivalent `java blahblahblah` line to what the IDE is trying to do? Don't worry about the slash-vs-backslash thing in the exception. Java nearly always shows paths using slashes, even on Windows, but that doesn't mean it's confused about them.

Comment: You should see a stack trace which shows where the exception originated. Basically, some piece of code somewhere thinks that `misc\test` is the name of a class. The stack trace will help to find that piece of code.

Comment: is misc a package here or a folder with source files?

Comment: misc is a package, yes. It is located in the Test Packages dir in NetBeans.

He is running the file by righ-clicking on it and Run file.

Stacktrace doesn't really show anything useful, just that the exception originated from ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java.248).

He can get a file to run if it's in the Source Packages dir. But the file works for me, even if it's in Test Packages. So I guess the problem isn't fatal as I first assumed, but it's still strange.

Answer (score 1):

When stating paths in java, it is a good idea to always use the unix separators, As they also work on Windows. Also when used in java Strings the '\' is the escape character so you always have to use two (note that this isn't true for your case).

Comment: Erm no, Java won't translate at all. Windows **just** supports it as well. Poke a bit round in `cmd` yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seams like *he* is trying to run `misc\test` like in

```
java misc\test
```

but the correct should be

```
java misc.test
```

*(also accepted `java misc/test`)*

<sup>**tested on Windows XP*</sup>

Not sure how that can happen from within the IDE. Are you sure he is not using something like ant to run it?
I would search for something like "misc/test" or "misc\test" and substitute it by "misc.test" (assuming `misc` is the package).

Comment: Hi, yeah he is running it directly from the IDE (right clicking on the file and selecting Run file). So I don't understand why this is happening.. Might just be NetBeans acting strangely. The files he cannot run is in the "Test packages" in NetBeans, but he can run files that are in the "Source packages".